# Use Delphi in Ruby on Rails on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delphi

I would like to use a Delphi program with its complete source codes as a library or external program in a Ruby on Rails application on Mac OS X 10.6, how can I accomplish it? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I think things aren't very clear here: if you have a Delphi *program*, you can't use it as a library. You can use a Delphi library as library :) or Delphi components, because BPLs are packages. You can use Delphi.NET on MacOSX because there's Mono for mac(as far as I remember). There are a bunch of things you can do, it all depends on what EXACTLY you do require to do :)

Comment: Thank for the replies, guys. What I'm exactly going to do, is to use some functionalities of this Delphi program via its corresponding interface for a Ruby on Rails project on Mac OS X. Any further suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @Andrea Can you really use Delphi .net to target Mono?

Comment: @David The current Delphi.NET is provided by RemObjects and it is my understanding that Mono runs on Mac and it is my understanding that Delphi.NET supports Mono. Have I ever tried it? No, that's why my remark stays in a comment and not in an answer :)
It would be beneficial to add that RemObjects made it a point back then to support Mono at the best they could and I have no news of this being changed in recent times... although I haven't spoken to Alex or Marc in a relatively long time about this kind of stuff :)

Comment: @andrea you are talking about prism not delphi .net

Comment: Prism is exactly that. Might have a different name, but that's what it is in latest incarnations, do you have info I don't? :) heehee

Comment: @user793981 that still does not say much, actually it confuses waters further. What are you trying to achieve? What are your set goals? Do you need them to reside necessarily on the same machine? Do you need an interaction at the API or at the functionality level? What are you trying to do? Do you have the sources for the Delphi program? Is it a program you did? What are your constraints?

Answer (score 3):

Delphi produces Windows apps only so you are probably looking at using Wine or perhaps compiling with FreePascal.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to compile it with FreePascal